# PHP/MySQL/AJAX - Refresh query values with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want my `header` to be consequently refreshed with fresh values from my `database`.

To achieve it i have created an `AJAX` post method:

**AJAX (edited):**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  function update() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "indextopgame.php",
    data: { id: "<?=$_SESSION['user']['id']?>"},
    success: function(data) { 
        $(".full-wrapper").html(data);
    }
});
      }

  setInterval( update, 5000 );
});
```

It should pass `$_SESSION['user']['id']` to `indextopgame.php` every 10 seconds.

`indextopgame.php` looks like that:

**PHP PART (edited):**

```
<?php

session_start();

$con = new mysqli("localhost","d0man94_eworld","own3d123","d0man94_eworld");

function sql_safe($s)
{
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $s = stripslashes($s);
    global $con;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $s);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{   
    $id = trim(sql_safe($_POST['id']));

    $data = "SELECT username, email, user_role, fbid, googleid, fname, lname, avatar, energy, energymax, health, healthmax, fame, edollar, etoken, companies, workid, city, function FROM members WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $data);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

            $_SESSION['user']['user_role'] = $row["id"];
            $_SESSION['user']['fbid'] = $row['fbid'];
            $_SESSION['user']['googleid'] = $row['googleid'];
            $_SESSION['user']['created'] = $row['created'];
            $_SESSION['user']['lastlogin'] = $row['lastlogin'];
            $_SESSION['user']['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['user']['fname'] = $row['fname'];
            $_SESSION['user']['lname'] = $row['lname'];
            $_SESSION['user']['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['user']['avatar'] = $row['avatar'];
            $_SESSION['user']['energy'] = $row['energy'];
            $_SESSION['user']['energymax'] = $row['energymax'];
            $_SESSION['user']['health'] = $row['health'];
            $_SESSION['user']['healthmax'] = $row['healthmax'];
            $_SESSION['user']['fame'] = $row['fame'];
            $_SESSION['user']['edollar'] = $row['edollar'];
            $_SESSION['user']['etoken'] = $row['etoken'];
            $_SESSION['user']['companies'] = $row['companies'];
            $_SESSION['user']['workid'] = $row['workid'];
            $_SESSION['user']['city'] = $row['city'];
            $_SESSION['user']['function'] = $row['function'];
        }

            echo $_SESSION['user']['energy'];
    }
}
?>
```

Still this wouldn't update the header with values i want, instead it just makes the header disappear. What's wrong with this code? Maybe there are other, more effective methods to refresh values from MySQL?

**EDIT:**

I've edited the `AJAX` / `PHP` code samples - it's working like that! But how may I echo all those variables? Echoing one after another seems to cause error again, since values will disappear from my header.

**EDIT2:**

Solved, I made a silly mistake with syntax... Thanks everyone for contributing!

Comment: if you dump data var on success .. do you get the right data ?

Comment: @Akin actually makes my header disappear rofl

Comment: Why do you send the session variable back and forth? It is already on the server so there is no reason to send it to the client and back to the server.

Comment: and your response is also empty. `success: function() { `, and echo mysqli resource id in response.??

Comment: you are echoing true/false. you know right

Comment: your console should have shown an error on your success line. the variable `data` does not exist

Comment: @Akin that's but it didn't - because i defined it as `[]` , now that i have fixed this it's not beingdefined at all

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the data that is sent back from the server in your ajax call:

```
success: function() { 
        $(".full-wrapper").html(data); 
    }
});
```

Should be:

```
success: function(data) { 
                  ^^^^ the returned data
        $(".full-wrapper").html(data); 
    }
});
```

You should also check that your php script actually echoes out something useful.

Comment: great, i'm halfway into making this work, now just the php data is not appearing meaning i need to work on php part. thanks jeroen!

Answer (score 1):

`data` options is missing in success method

```
success: function(data) {                      
   $(".full-wrapper").html(data); 
}
```

Also you should have to echo that content in php file which you want to show in header.